# How to Overwrite the Saved form with Submitted in infopath library

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have created infopath library also deployed the infopath form as content type. When i open new form and Save into the library with "My Exepnse Saved" Named. When i open saved form and made some changes and Submit into library the new form will be Submitted (submited Form as Name  "EXp-FirstName-Now()"). But i don't want to do that i just want to overwrite the previous saved form (My Exepnse Saved") with this new submitted form. Is there any workaround for the same?? See i don't want to use different library for save and submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done quite easily:

- create a new node in your datasource
- on your submit button, add a rule that (just before saving) checks if that node is empty. If it's empty you fill it with the name you want your form to have. Change your dataconnection to use that field as the filename.

So... the first time you save, the new node will be empty so it will be filled. The next time, it will already have a value and that value will be used for saving the document. Of course, make sure that you enable to option to overwrite existing items.